# Numpy, matrix of integer list

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the next list

```
lst = [([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1, 2], [1, 1, 0, 0]), ([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0])]
```

each set has 4 lists that contain 4 integers inside.

I need a matrix in numpy like this one, (for the first set, for example):

```
numpy_matrix = [ [0, 0, 1, 1] , [0, 1, 0, 1]
                [0, 2, 1, 2] , [1, 1, 0, 0] ]
```

notice that is a 2x2 matrix, and inside instead of saving integers is saving a list of those integers so I can do something like this:

```
print(numpy_array[0, 0][3]) # output: 1
```

I've tried this but didn't work:

```
np.matrix(lst[0]).reshape(2,-1)
# output:
# matrix([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#         [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: `arr = np.array(lst[0]).reshape(2, 2, 4)`?

Comment: Yey, now It worked, could you elaborate why the `4` is nedeed there? Please, post it as an answer so I can give your reply as correct! thanks :)

Comment: Look at `np.array(lst).shape`.  It's (2,4,4), right?  What shape do you want?  Your focus on `lst[0]` makes things a bit unclear, but I think you want (2,2,2,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1, 2], [1, 1, 0, 0]),
       ([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0])]

arr = np.array(lst[0]).reshape(2, 2, 4)
print(arr)
```

**Output**

```
[[[0 0 1 1]
  [0 1 0 1]]

 [[0 2 1 2]
  [1 1 0 0]]]
```

The expression:

```
.reshape(2, 2, 4)
```

reshape the array to a 3-dimensional array where the length of the first dimension is 2, the second one is 2 and the last one is 4.